# Django: Fields aren't loaded in the forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I've a user profile and would like allow the user update everything about himself(username, password, name and others informations). With the code below, the password1 and password2 fields aren't loaded and the clean_username method is not called. To complete, when I call is_valid method it always return False but with no errors.

Could anybody help me? Thank you.

```
#forms.py
class UserProfileForm(ModelForm):
    c_user = None
    error_messages = {
        'duplicate_username': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        'password_mismatch': _("The two password fields didn't match."),
    }
    username = forms.RegexField(label=_("Username"), max_length=30,
        regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
        help_text = _("Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and "
                      "@/./+/-/_ only."),
        error_messages = {
            'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and "
                         "@/./+/-/_ characters.")})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if kwargs.has_key('instance'):
            current_user = kwargs.get('instance').user
            self.c_user = current_user
            self.password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                widget=forms.PasswordInput, required = False)
            self.password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                widget=forms.PasswordInput, required = False,
                help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
        else: 
            self.password1 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
                widget=forms.PasswordInput)
            self.password2 = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
                widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))

    def clean_username(self):
        # Since User.username is unique, this check is redundant,
        # but it sets a nicer error message than the ORM. See #13147.
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if (self.c_user == None) or (self.c_user.username != username):
            try:
                User.objects.get(username=username)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                return username
            raise forms.ValidationError(self.error_messages['duplicate_username'])

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1", "")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data["password2"]
        if password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['password_mismatch'])
        return password2

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude=('user')
```

>

```
#views.py

@csrf_protect
def update_user(request):
    user = request.user
    user_profile = user.get_profile()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        initials = {'username':user.username,
                'email':user.email,
                'name':user_profile.name,
                'birth_date':user_profile.birth_date,
                'weight':user_profile.weight,
                'height':user_profile.height,
                'smoke':user_profile.smoke,
                'drink_alcohol':user_profile.drink_alcohol,
                'alergies':user_profile.alergies,
                }
        form = UserProfileForm(initial=initials)
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.save(commit=False)
            user.username = request.POST.get('username')
            user.save()
            f.user = user
            f.save()
            print request.POST.get('username')
            return redirect('/')
    return render_to_response('profile.html', {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**UPDATE:** Thank you Daniel Roseman! Now I'm having problem just with the fields password1 and password2. They aren't being loaded.

Comment: Why are you sending form.asp_p() to template? Just send form object to template and access it as form.as_p() in template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
self.fields['password1'] = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"),
            widget=forms.PasswordInput, required = False)
self.fields['password2'] = forms.CharField(label=_("Password confirmation"),
            widget=forms.PasswordInput, required = False,
            help_text = _("Enter the same password as above, for verification."))
```

Comment: Thank you guy! Worked just like I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error: you have overwritten the signature of the form's `__init__` method, so that the first argument is `current_user`. So when in your POST block you instantiate the form with `UserProfileForm(request.POST, instance=user_profile)`, the data dictionary is taken for the current_user parameter and the actual data parameter is empty. Because it's empty, the form is not bound, so there are no errors.

The best way to override a form's `__init__` is to take any new parameters from `args` or `kwargs`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user = kwargs.pop('current_user')
    super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    etc.
```

Comment: Isn't the same thing? Because what I'm passing to the constructor are the args and kwargs.

Comment: No, it's not the same thing at all. Try it and see. The problem is when you *don't* pass `current_user`, which happens in your POST block.

Comment: Yes is really different! It cleaned my mind and I'm updating the code of the question. But I'm still with the non-loaded fields problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Should it not just be {'form':form, } in the view def.
Then in the template use {{ form.as_p }}